# Leaflet-easyprint - marker label text shrink

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I am using Leaflet easy-print plugin to print the map. But in the exported map marker label text shrink and shows ... but on the map, it looks ok. Can someone please help me how to fix that?

[image: Exported png]

Comment: do you have an example

Comment: Please see attached - Exported png